# How to confine a moving div inside a containing div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to code a little game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The red block is the player, the green block is the enemy. I have a div containing these two, with a black border. How do I keep the red block inside the border? I use the arrow keys to move the red block so code that I've found online hasn't been helpful because it all relates to draggable elements using the mouse.
I'll place my code here for my index, the css and the js.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch (e.which) {
    case 37: //left arrow key
      $(".player").finish().animate({
        containment: ".container",
        left: "-=5"
      });
      break;
    case 38: //up arrow key
      $(".player").finish().animate({
        containment: ".container",
        top: "-=5"
      });
      break;
    case 39: //right arrow key
      $(".player").finish().animate({
        containment: ".container",
        left: "+=5"
      });
      break;
    case 40: //bottom arrow key
      $(".player").finish().animate({
        containment: ".container",
        top: "+=5"
      });
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.player {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #9C2259;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}

.badguy {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #376F46;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Tim T. Hall" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Test, Testing" />

  <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="player"></div>
      <div class="badguy"></div>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
```

Comment: `.animate` only can handle CSS properties... And not all. There is no `containement` property in CSS. As you mentioned, that exist in jQuery-ui `.draggable` method only. You will havve to calculate and compare the postion to skip the animation when a boundary is reached.

Comment: [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) will be usefull for those calculations.

Answer (score 0):

@donnieth65,

Not entirely sure of the description of your post, however, I have put some code together to detect when the child div called player touches or reaches the parent border, once this happens, I stop player from continue towards that direction to avoid leaving its parents body or wrapper. I decided to validate this with some conditionals to first find the current position and if this was inside the parents body then we will move around using the current switch statement rules that you have established already. I certainly hope this helps, m8!

```js
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    // Assign elements to variables
    let player = $('.player');
    let container = $('.container');
  // These 2 vars will help us getting the bottom and right boundaries
  // so that we can stop the div from moving outside of the parent
 let getBottom = parseInt(player.position().top + player.outerHeight(true));
 let getRight = parseInt(player.position().left + player.outerWidth(true));

    // Are these elements touching the parent edges?
    // If is so, let us get them back in by 1 unit
    // first for the top case
    if (player.position().top < 0) {
        player.css({
            top: 1
        });
    }
    // Then for the left case
    else if (player.position().left < 0) {
        player.css({
            left: 1
        });
    }
    // Then for the right case
    else if (getRight > 692) {
        player.css({
            left: 640
        });
    }
    // Last for the bottom case
    else if (getBottom > 492) {
        player.css({
            top:440
        });
    }
    // If is not touching any edge, then increase their position
    // This will be validated with a switch case now
    else {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37: //left arrow key
                $(".player").finish().animate({
                    left: "-=5px"
                });
                break;
            case 38: //up arrow key
                $(".player").finish().animate({
                    top: "-=5px"
                });
                break;
            case 39: //right arrow key
                $(".player").finish().animate({
                    left: "+=5px"
                });
                break;
            case 40: //bottom arrow key
                $(".player").finish().animate({
                    top: "+=5px"
                });
                break;
        } //End of Switch case
    } // End of main conditional statement with else
});
```

```css
html, body {margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden}

.player {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #9C2259;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
}

.badguy {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #376F46;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Tim T. Hall" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Test, Testing" />

    <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="player"></div>
            <div class="badguy"></div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been useful. However, I was testing it and it seems to work for the top and the left but not for the right and the bottom.

Comment: Please proceed to try again, I have made some extra adjustments, folk!